# Strange behaviors with Spring Boot and Log4J2

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I am running into some strange problems when running my Spring Boot application. It has been configured to use Log4J2 as its logger (the Logback logger has been disabled).

log4j2.xml:

```
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="serviceName">$${sys:service.name}</Property>
    <Property name="serviceId">$${sys:service.id}</Property>

    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
      [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %t %-5p: %c{2}:%L - %m%n
    </Property>

    <Property name="STATS_PATTERN">
      %m%n
    </Property>

    <Property name="logFile">logs/$${sys:service.name}-$${sys:service.id}</Property>
    <Property name="statsFile">metrics/$${sys:service.name}-$${sys:service.id}_stats.json</Property>
    <!--
    <Property name="logFile">logs/${serviceName}-${serviceId}</Property>
    <Property name="statsFile">metrics/${serviceName}-${serviceId}_stats.json</Property>
    -->
  </Properties>

  <Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${logFile}.current-session.log"
      filePattern="${logFile}.%i.log.gz" ignoreExceptions="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>

    <File name="StatsFile" fileName="${statsFile}" append="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>${STATS_PATTERN}</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="<package>.StatsWriter" level="info" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="StatsFile" />
    </Logger>

    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Main Issue**

I have some variable substitution in the log4j2.xml file to allow for variation, specifically for log file names. When I run the application, the log files are created in the correct directory and do appear to have actual log content. The problem is that they're named incorrectly. For example, instead of `Client-1.current-session.log`, the file is named `${sys:service.name}-${sys:service.id}.current-session.log`. Obviously the variable substitution did not take place as planned.

The properties `service.name` and `service.id` are Spring Boot configuration parameters currently defined in an associated application.yml file. I had thought that the properties in the file would be available, but that's obviously not the case.

Is there a way to make the application.yml properties available here? If this is not doable, what are suggestions for other ways to accomplish this?

**Secondary Question**

When I've been executing the application in my test environment, I have the logger set to output to console:

```
<Root level="info">
  <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</Root>
```

When it executes, output is displayed on the console, but oddly, the log file is also created. Why would that be?

**NOTE**:

There is an existing SO item ([Use Spring boot application properties in log4j2.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941104/use-spring-boot-application-properties-in-log4j2-xml/49982765#49982765))  (it is the second answer) that sort of addresses this, but it seems (as the author admits) kind of hacky. I have not tried it (yet).

I'm a little confused by references to application-"profile".yml and log4j2-spring.xml. I'm not familiar with these variations on these file names. What is the significance of these variations (of both file types)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your **main question**, your file name is `log4j2.xml` you should use `log4j2-spring.xml` instead since this way you allow Spring Boot to have better control on Log4j2.

One of the benefits it's the possibility to integrate the variables you are missing. This is probably due to using `log4j2.xml` files makes log4j2 to initialize before spring boot, while using `log4j2-spring.xml` makes Spring Boot to initialize log4j2.

As the [SpringBoot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-logging) states:

> When possible, we recommend that you use the -spring variants for your logging configuration (for example, logback-spring.xml rather than logback.xml). If you use standard configuration locations, Spring cannot completely control log initialization.

You can take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15649) opened by a guys asking for `log4j2.xml` vs `log4j2-spring.xml`

For your **second question**, because you have 2 loggers... simply as that:

```xml
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="<package>.StatsWriter" level="info" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="StatsFile" />   <---- This one creates your file
    </Logger>

    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
```

Regarding your **third question**:

> I'm a little confused by references to application-"profile".yml and log4j2-spring.xml. I'm not familiar with these variations on these file names. What is the significance of these variations (of both file types)?

The variation on `application-"profile".xxx` it's a way that you allow spring boot to take different configurations based on those profile files. You can start your app with "dev" parameters (dev database locally) but on production you can use different parameters. You can control how to bootstrap different profiles through different ways, one very common is executing your app like `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod application.jar`

Related to `log4j2-spring.xml`, it's stated above, to allow Spring Boot to properly initialize log4j2 (or whatever logging tool you use).

Comment: For you're answer to my second question - I understand that I would also get the "stats" file, but what I don't understand is why I also get the log file that contains the console output. I'm not specifying a logger using the RollingFile appender.

Comment: @JosephGagnon I can see that you should have 2 log files, and the console. If you have actually 3 files then you should open a new question providing details only related to your logging config. This way is simpler to track question/answer. However, did you move to `log4j2-spring.xml` this is a must.

Comment: I will be trying out with log4j2-spring.xml next.

Comment: @JosephGagnon I'd recommend you that if your main question is solved, then mark this question as answered and open a new one for each specific question. Community is not keep to ask multiple different questions in the same thread.

Comment: @JosephGagnon another thing I noticed is that you are using `$${sys:service.name}` which `$$` is escaping dollar sign. Can you try using only `${sys:service.name}` instead. I think using `-spring.xml` suffix plus one `$` sign should fix main issue.

Comment: I was hoping your last suggestion would fix it, but it has not. I changed the file as follows:
    <Property name="serviceName">${sys:service.name}</Property>   
    <Property name="serviceId">${sys:service.id}</Property>       
    <Property name="logFile">logs/${serviceName}-${serviceId}</Property>
    <Property name="statsFile">metrics/${serviceName}-${serviceId}_stats.json</Property>