# log4j2 spring boot lookup can't read property from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, log4j2

I want log4j2-spring.xml to read a property from the application.properties file. But seems log4j2-spring.xml is unable to read this. I have read https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#SpringLookup to implement this.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60504812/2952011) on this site. Tried like this as well. But it didn't help me.

My build.gradle is like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

ext {
    log4j2version = '2.14.1'
}

dependencies {

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.18'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.18'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'

    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-spring-cloud-config-client:${log4j2version}"
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:${log4j2version}"
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:${log4j2version}"
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude group: "ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-classic"
        exclude group: "org.springframework.cloud", module: "spring-cloud-bus"
    }
}
```

application.properties file is:

```
commission.base.path1=C:/Users/user1/Downloads/demo1
logging.config=classpath:log4j2-spring.xml

spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
```

log4j2-spring.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{2}:%L - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="CATALINA-FILE" fileName="$${spring:commission.base.path1}/logs/catalina.log"
                     filePattern="$${spring:commission.base.path1}/logs/archived/catalina_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{20}:%L - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 GB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="CATALINA-FILE"/>
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </root>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

But everytime I run the code, I am getting this exception:

```
2021-05-21 21:28:38,409 main ERROR Unable to create file ${spring:commission.base.path1}/logs/catalina.log java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:720)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:704)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1000)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:940)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:932)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:551)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:241)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:287)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:627)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:304)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spring.boot.Log4j2CloudConfigLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(Log4j2CloudConfigLoggingSystem.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:181)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.initialize(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:163)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spring.boot.Log4j2CloudConfigLoggingSystem.initialize(Log4j2CloudConfigLoggingSystem.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:373)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:144)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:373)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325)
    at com.example.demo1.Demo1Application.main(Demo1Application.java:12)
```

How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try converting $$ to single $ in log4j2-spring.xml

Comment: tried already. @Sachin

Comment: I see that LoggingApplicationListener class initializes logger twice. First default SpringBoot logger without resolved applocation configuration properties, so it tries to find literal path "${spring:commission.base.path1}/logs/catalina.log" which throws exception. Then the second time correctly configured logger with resolved path gets injected. Also the setup looks hacky, but can't find any better example of how to correctly use log4j-spring-cloud-config-client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just added

> implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-spring-boot"

in build.gradle and it is working now.

Implementation of

> implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'

is enough for using log4j2 version 2.14.1 as spring boot version is 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT. No need to add dependencies of **org.apache.logging.log4j** explicitly for this.

So my final build.gradle is:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.18'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.18'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'

    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-spring-boot"
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}
```

And **no** need to keep this in **application.properties**:

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
```

And yes, [Official Documentation of log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#SpringLookup) should add that **log4j-spring-boot** dependency is enough to implement spring lookup.

Answer (score 2):

The question is do you need Log4j configuration over Spring Cloud?

**Problem**

If not, I would say **org.apache.logging.log4j:2.14.1** dependency is an overkill. It brings Spring Cloud dependencies that you won't need. In a way that I still didn't figure out, it also interfeeres with **spring-boot-starter-log4j2** causing initialization of logging context multiple times and then as a sideffect you have this excpetion at the startup as property from Spring is not resolved.

**Solution**

Mind you don't need whole **log4j-spring-cloud-config-client** and even **spring-boot-starter-log4j2**.

Following dependencies will set up your logging context:

- log4j
- log4j-slf4j-impl
- log4j-spring-boot

I have put an [example program in GitHub repository](https://github.com/rivancic/log4j). Variable names are slightly changed and there are comments explaining what each dependency is for.

Excerpt of Gradle build file

```
dependencies {

  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.18'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.18'

  // Spring Boot dependency
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

  // Logging dependencies

  // Base Log4j 2
  implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:${log4j2version}"

  // Will resolve spring properties
  implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-spring-boot:${log4j2version}"

  // Log4j 2 to Slf4j binder
  implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:${log4j2version}"
}
```

[Official documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#Spring_Boot_Lookup) should say that **log4j-spring-boot** dependency is enough to resolve lookup variables from Spring configuration files.

But in case you really need to configure Log4J over cloud configurations then again you have to carefully look on how the dependencies are resolved and which ones do you really need.

Answer (score 0):

try this single $ istead of $$

fileName="${spring:commission.base.path1}/logs/catalina.log"
filePattern="${spring:commission.base.path1}/logs/archived/catalina_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">